# Parse EBNF with Megaparsec nested sepBy

Tags: parsing, haskell, ebnf, megaparsec

As an exercise I try to parse a EBNF/ABNF grammar with Megaparsec. I got trivial stuff like terminals and optionals working, but I'm struggling with alternatives. With this grammar:

```
S ::= 'hello' ['world'] IDENTIFIER LITERAL | 'test';
```

And this code:

```
production :: Parser Production
production = sepBy1 alternativeTerm (char '|') >>= return . Production

alternativeTerm :: Parser AlternativeTerm
alternativeTerm = sepBy1 term space >>= return . AlternativeTerm

term :: Parser Term
term = terminal
    <|> optional
    <|> identifier
    <|> literal
```

I get this error:

```
unexpected '|'
expecting "IDENTIFIER", "LITERAL", ''', '[', or white space
```

I guess the alternativeTerm parser is not returning to the production parser when it encounters a sequence that it cannot parse and throws an error instead.

What can I do about this? Change my ADT of an EBNF or should I somehow flatten the parsing. But then again, how can I do so?

Comment: Does it work how you want it if you use `(try alternativeTerm)` in `production`? Just a guess, since it seems like you need backtracking.

Comment: It seems like the parsing does not escape the inner `sepBy1`. It tries to parse the | as `term` and fails. What about using `sepEndBy1` instead?

Comment: @Lazersmoke try does not work

Comment: @PhilippKiener which sepBy should I replace?

Comment: The one in `alternativeTerm`. This only works when there is a guaranteed space between the last term and the |, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to expand my previous comment into a full answer.

Your grammar is basically a list of list of terms seperated (and ended) by whitespace, which in turn is seperated by |. Your solution with `sepBy1` does not work because there is a trailing whitespace after `LITERAL` - `sepBy1` assumes there is another term following that whitespace and tries to apply `term` to the |, which fails.

If your `alternativeTerm` is guaranteed to end with a whitespace character (or multiple), rewrite your `alternativeTerm` as follows:

```
alternativeTerm = (term `sepEndBy1` space) >>= return . AlternativeTerm
```

Comment: Thanks, that works now. I will most likely add a tokenizer, so I dont have to deal with spaces any more